# Why Does My Recursive Function Return Undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand why `return weights_data` returns `undefined`, and `console.log(weights_data)` returns something.

```
const getWeightReattributeProportionally = (weights_data, weight, z = 0) => {

  weights_data.forEach( (r, i) => weights_data[i] = (r * weight) + r );

  if ( weights_data.reduce( (a, b) => a + b) >= 0.9999999999999999 ) {

    console.log(weights_data);

    return weights_data;

  } else {

    getWeightReattributeProportionally(weights_data, weight *= weight, z += 1);

  }

}

const data = [0.12, 0.22, 0.32, 0.18]

const aaaa = getWeightReattributeProportionally(data, 0.16)

console.log(aaaa)
```

Comment: the condition is never met. it always returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that you need to return the result of the recursive function:

```js
const func = (weights_data, weight, z = 0) => {
  weights_data.forEach((r, i) => weights_data[i] = (r * weight) + r)
  if (weights_data.reduce((a, b) => a + b) >= 0.9999999999999999) {
    console.log(weights_data)
    return weights_data
  } else {
    return func(weights_data, weight *= weight, z += 1) // NEW!
  }
}

const data = [0.12, 0.22, 0.32, 0.18]

const aaaa = func(data, 0.16)

console.log(aaaa)
```

Also, you have a bug in your code: `z` is never used anywhere in your function

Comment: Please upvote and mark my answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your recursive function uses side effects (e.g., manipulating global/shared state, writing to a file, etc.) to do its job, every invocation, including the outermost, must return its results to its caller.

If it doesn't, how can the caller know what the recursive call did?